# Pass arguments to a slot using QTimer

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I have written a pyQt client-server application. (python:3.2.2 , pyQT:4.8.6)
The sender sends a message to the listening receivers, and the receivers send a response to the sender. I dont want the response to be sent instantly, but after a small delay.

This is part of the receiver code:

```
----------------------------- msghandler.py-----------------------------------
class MsgHandler(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.mSec1Timer = None

    def setParentUI(self, p):
        self.parentUI = p

    def handle_ask(self, ID, stamp, length, cargo, peerSocket):
        print("Incoming:ASK")
        #self.mSec1Timer.timeout.connect(lambda:self.send_msg_reply(peerSocket))
        self.mSec1Timer.timeout.connect(self.dummyFunc) #Works
        self.mSec1Timer.timeout.connect(lambda:self.dummyFunc())#See Rem-1
        self.mSec1Timer.timeout.connect(lambda:self.shouldGiveError())#See Rem-2
        self.parentUI.timerStart.emit(5)

    @pyqtSlot(tuple)
    def send_msg_reply(self, peerSocket):
        print("This is not printed")
        self.mSec1Timer.timeout.disconnect()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def dummyFunc(self):
        print("dummy @ ",QDateTime.currentMSecsSinceEpoch())
        self.mSec1Timer.timeout.disconnect()
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

from msghandler import *
class DialogUIAgent(QDialog):

    timerStart = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        self.myHandler = MsgHandler()
        self.myHandler.setParentUI(self)

        self.myTimer = QTimer()
        self.myTimer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.myHandler.mSec1Timer = self.myTimer

        self.timerStart.connect(self.startMyTimer)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def startMyTimer(self, msec):
        self.myTimer.start(msec)
```

For testing the behaviour first, i used `self.mSec1Timer.timeout.connect(self.dummyFunc)`, and the output was as expected:

```
Incoming:ASK
dummy @  1322491256315
Incoming:ASK
dummy @  1322491260310
Incoming:ASK
dummy @  1322491265319
Incoming:ASK
dummy @  1322491270323
Incoming:ASK
dummy @  1322491275331
```

But when i used `self.mSec1Timer.timeout.connect(lambda:self.send_msg_reply(peerSocket))`, the slot was never called. Output:

```
Incoming:ASK
Incoming:ASK
Incoming:ASK
Incoming:ASK
```

Why is this happening, and what can i do to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT :**
Remark-1:
dummyFunc worked before, but it does not work with `lambda:self.dummyFunc()`

Remark-2:
I was expecting an Error with `lambda:self.shouldGiveError()`, because there is no such function, but instead i get nothing.

Is this a problem of the way that i use lambda?

Comment: It looks to me like your example does not work because the first call to dummyFunc disconnects the signal ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [QObject.invokeMethod()](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qmetaobject.html)?

It has been supported since PyQt 4.4 and it should allow you to call a slot with arguments when you don't have a signal that match.

Comment: It looks nice, but i dont know how to use it with the timeout signal of QTimer. I am trying to see examples

Comment: Hmm... well, the way QObject.connect() works is to find the slots that have the maximum number of arguments (or less) to match the slot. So, you cannot really connect it up to a slot that has more arguments. You need to marshall the arguments somehow. So, in your example you will need to store your peerSocket and then pass it along in your "no-argument" timeout slot. Sorry that I answered the "wrong" question."